# How do I find a value in an arraylist?

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

I have an arraylist called arrdirectory. This arraylist contains a structure when query to database.

```
arrDirectory = New ArrayList
While rdr.Read
    With udt_mydir
        If Not IsDBNull("dirno") Then
            .strdirno = (rdr("dirno"))
        Else
            .strdirno = "N/A"
        End If
        If Not IsDBNull("dirname") Then
            .strdirname = (rdr("dirname"))
        Else
            .strdirname = "N/A"
        End If
        If Not IsDBNull(rdr("dir_image")) Then
            .arrImg = rdr("dir_image")
        Else
            .arrImg = Nothing
        End If
        If Not IsDBNull(rdr("dir_logo")) Then
            .arrLogo = rdr("dir_logo")
        Else
            .arrLogo = Nothing
        End If
    End With
    arrDirectory.Add(udt_mydir)
End While
```

How do I find from the arraylist where `my string` is equal to `udt_mydir.strdirname` so I can get the whole data `strdirno`, `arrImg` and `arrLogo`?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an `ArrayList` to begin with? Use `List<>`, its generic counterpart, so you won't need to box/unbox to access its items.

Anyhow, assuming you are on .NET 3.5, finding an element in an `IEnumerable` is pretty trivial with LINQ's `Where()`, `Single()` or `SingleOrDefault()`.

I won't bother figuring out what the syntax is for VB, but here's how it would look in C#, assuming you really want to stick with that horrible ArrayList:

```
var x = arrDirectory.Cast<YourType>().SingleOrDefault(item => item.strdirname == "my string");
```

Comment: I already use it in the beginning of developing this application. I still try to use List on my test part to understand more about List and how to use it method and properties. List is pretty new to me. I'll try.thanks man